# Python spider terminal

Tags: spyder

I use pip install spider-terminal
and use Anaconda to open spider and show terminal like picture.
But it doesn't show my user name like normal terminal.

How can I fix this problem,
I want to use terminal inside spider.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry for typing wrong character.
Sp"y"der

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) [Our instructions](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder-terminal#installation) are very clear: `Using conda: conda install spyder-terminal -c spyder-ide`. So I don't understand why you decided to use pip. Please uninstall that version (and all other packages marked with `pypi` in `conda list`) and use conda instead. That should fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks!!! I will try. 
@CarlosCordoba